# Resolving asset location issues using SASS in PHPStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I have a project where the basic asset folder structure looks like this:

```
/css
/css/sass
/js
/images
```

When I compile the SASS files, it places them into the css folder above.  I do it this way to try and keep my directory structure logical and simple.

I'm using relative paths in my SASS files to link to images:

```
background: url(../images/foobar.png);
```

However, since the path is relative from the CSS directory, PHPStorm flags it as an error.

Is there any way to configure PHPStorm to be able to recognise assets from a destination path, and not just directly from the SASS file?

Comment: Use paths relative to the website root (i.e. `url(/images/foobar.png);`)? ... or save `sass` folder on the same level as `css`.

Comment: The project i'm working on is a legacy Kohana 2.3 app, so it uses the Cascading File System, so using paths relative to the root is a no-no.  I could move the sass folder up a level sure, i'm just wondering if there's a way to configure PHPStorm to work in this manner or not.

Comment: Well ... as I understand the css code has no errors but sass does. The only thing you may try in such case is to mark `css` folder as **resource root** (right click on it in Project View and go from there).

Comment: In our project we do have sass on the same level as css. But then we have sass/components, which ends up with the same problem. So, a solution would be nice :)

Comment: Not an answer, but a workaround is to open up the menu on the error (place cursor in it and press "alt" + "enter" (mac)) and navigate to "Create Directory Assets" -> "Edit inspection profile setting", then modify the highlighted inspection setting. Either disable it entirely or change the severity

Comment: @LazyOne I did it, and paths no longer highlighted as wrong. I can Ctrl+click on them and files are open. However, `scss.bat` can't find them.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer In such case you have to configure your SCSS compiler to tell where to find them. Cannot help on this unfortunately as I'm not using SCSS myself.

Answer (score -1):

Replace:

```
background: url(../images/foobar.png);
```

With:

```
background: image-url('foobar.png');
```

To use the compass image-url() function. The inspection errors from PHPStorm will then disappear, and compass will automatically generate the correct path based on the image resource root.